# Const qualifier in getter method

Tags: c++

Why getters and setters needs `const` qualifier? Ok, I suppose the one reason for setter method is to prevent `value` from changing in method body that allows make less errors. Looks not very reasonable for me, is that only for this reason?

And I'm totally confused why I need it in getter method?

```
class turbo
{
    int i = 10;
    public:
    void setI(const int value) {i=value}
    int getI()  const {return i;}
}
```

Comment: You are correct about the `const` on the setter, that is the only reason for it.

Comment: Those two consts mean totally different things. That setter doesn't need a const. If the parameter was passed by reference, it should be const.

Comment: getters and setters violate encapsulation. You should tell your object what you want it to do, not ask it for information and make a decision out side of it. http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask

Answer (score 3):

Suppose I have a variable of type `const turbo`. Then I'm allowed to call methods marked `const` and **no others**. Furthermore I can be sure that a call to such a method is not going to change the state of the `turbo` instance. This is because member functions marked `const` cannot change member variables or call non-`const` methods on them.

So, in general, getters can be `const` as they don't change the object's state. Setters should not be `const`. Better still, avoid writing setters at all since it can be difficult to control the internal consistency of an object and tend to complicate multithreaded programming: set up as much as you can in the constructor.

This gives you a remarkable improvement in program stability. That's why C++ programmers strive for as much `const`-correctness as possible.

(Of course C++ allows you to remove these benefits using `const_cast` and `mutable` but this should be done with caution).

Answer (score 1):

Any `const` function promises not to modify any member variables of that class. For getters, that is trivial, but the following reason is why they must be `const`:

For other `const` functions in that class, they may only use `const` functions as well.

If you had some function:

```
int turbo::foo() const
{
    int i = getI();
    return 2 * i;
}
```

If your function `getI()` was not also `const`, the compiler would tell you that `turbo::getI()` was non-`const` and therefore `foo()` could not be const.

Answer (score 1):

If you qualify an argument as being constant, it shows the caller that you won't change that argument inside the function. In your case this is useless as `int value` makes a copy anyway. But if you use a reference `int& value` or a pointer `int* value` it makes sense to declare it `const` as otherwise a caller might assume that `value` will be modified.

The `const`-qualifier after the argument list has a different meaning.
Functions that are declared `const` can be called on a `const` object of that type, while functions that don't have that qualifier cannot.
So if you instantiate an object of class `turbo` like `const turbo x;` then it's possible to only call `const` member functions on it. That means non-modifying member functions, which in your case is only `int getI() const;` while `void setI(const int);` cannot be called as it would modify the object which is declared to be `const`.

So arguments that are either references or pointers because a copy would be too expensive are declared `const` if they are not modified by the function to signal the caller that they can assume that no modifications will be made to that object.
While functions that are declared to be `const` are used for operations that don't modify the object on which they are called as for example getters.

Answer (score 0):

So that you can use it with constant objects and also tells the compiler that the object is not altered

Answer (score 0):

`const` qualifiers for input-arguments and return-values are required only if you pass/return them **by reference**. Taking your code, for example, `const` qualifiers would be required if it looked like this:

```
class turbo
{
private:
    int i;
public:
    void setI(const int& value) {i=value;}
    const int& getI() const {return i;}
};
```

It usually becomes handy when dealing with types that are "more complicated" than `int`.

A `const` qualifier on a member function is meant to prevent you (or other users) from changing member variables inside the function, if that was your original intention when you designed the class.

Answer (score 0):

Between these two function declarations

```
void setI(const int value) {i=value}
int getI()  const {return i;}
```

there is a big difference.

The first function declaration is equivalent to

```
void setI( int value);
```

and the both declare the same one function. To these functions the argument is passed by value that is the unctions use a copy of an argument. The original argument itself will not be changed.

The only difference between these two function declarations is that inside the body of the first function the parameter is considered as a local constant variable. However there is no any greate vsense for these function definitions.

As for the getter then the qualifier const means that the function may not change data members of the object. You may not to write for example

```
int getI()  const {return ++i;}
```

That is the qualifier const says that the state of the object will not be changed after a function call.

Answer (score 0):

Made some modification to demonstrate several conditions for setter/getter:

```
class turbo
{
public:
    void setI(int value) { i = value; }                // #1
    void setS(const std::string& value) { s = value; } // #2
    int getI() const { return i; }                     // #3
    const std::string& getS1() const { return s; }     // #4
    std::string getS2() const { return s + "blah"; }   // #5

private:
    int i = 10;
    std::string s;
}
```

---

`const` for member function signature means this getter can not modify it's owner (i.e. the object).

`const` before argument means the argument can not be changed inside the function.

---

For setter:

if argument is native type, no need for `const`, just pass by value and it's fine. (#1)

if argument is complicate class, use `const` reference to avoid unnecessary temporary object construction. (#2)

you can't add `const` for member function signature, because you are modifying the object! (#1, #2)

---

For getter:

if return type is native, just return it, no need const. (#3)

if return type is complicate class, there are 2 cases:

1. you are returning a member, and you are providing the value only for looking, then you should add `const` and return by reference. (#4)
2. you are returning some calculated and temporary result using your member, then you should return by value, and no need for `const` (because there there are no available reference for such result) (#5)

you should add `const` for member function signature, because the getter means to provide some value, not to modify the object. (#4, #5)

---

In practice, you would pass your object by `const` reference whenever possible, in such case the caller using your object can only use `const` member function you designed, in which case it's very possible for your getters

```
// the function is called display, so it theoretically should not modify t
// so we pass t by const reference, therefore t can only call const member function
void display(const turbo& t)
{
    std::string s = t.getS2();
    // blahblah
}
```